# import succeeds for one file but not another in the same directory

Tags: python, python-import

I have a project folder named proja. It contains several files:

```
"__init__.py"
classa.py
classb.py
classc.py
```

I have a subfolder in proja named folderb. It has an ""**init**.py"", also. This folder contains a py script with the following import statements. It imports classa but fails on classb.

```
from classa import classa
from classb import classb
from class import classc
```

It doesn't matter if I run the script from the proja: "python folderb/imptest.py" or of I cd to folderb and run: "python imptest.py".

It always fails with: "ImportError: No module named classb..."

Why will it import from one file but not another in the same location?

Comment: I found that it works if I do a sys.path.append...

But, I don't understand why it would work for one file in that directory but not for another file in that same directory. I'd like to have to avoid the sys.path.append, if possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there is a function or method of name `classb` in the file `classb.py`

Once run the file with this :

```
import classa
import classb
import classc
```

If this commands work then file paths are ok and you should look inside the files.

If you do this and it works check the inside of file `classb.py`,
 otherwise post the error. It will help.

Comment: Thanks. After verifying that file names, class names, etc., were correct, I modified my import statements to include the complete path from the root of my $PYTHONROOT. That worked.

    from parentdir.proja import classa
    from parentdir.proja import classb
    from parentdir.proja import classc


Still not sure why one file imported and another in the same directory didn't. But, I have a working, appropriate method for making this work.